# how can i use lodash flow with find and get togther?

Tags: lodash, ramda.js

i tried to convevt my code from ramda to lodash and i have some problems with flow method.

ramda example works great

```
const campsModeSelectedIndex =
    aRouteId &&
    R.pipe(
      R.find((r: any) => r['pointIndex'] === aTerraIndex && r['routeIndex'] === aRouteIndex),
      R.prop('wayOfLiving'),
    )(allSelectedRoutes);
```

lodash example is does't work

```
const test = aRouteId &&
    _.flow([
      lodashFind((r: any) => r['pointIndex'] === aTerraIndex && r['routeIndex'] === aRouteIndex),
      lodashGet('wayOfLiving'),])(allSelectedRoutes)
```

Answer (score 4):

For functions to work with a combinator like `R.pipe` or `_.flow()`, the functions need to be fixed arity, curried, and iteratee first/data last:

- Fixed arity - the function should always accept a predefined number of parameters, with not optional parameters.
  For example `R.prop` accepts the property, and the object, so it has a fixed arity of 2. Lodash's `_.get()` accepts the object, the path, and an optional parameters of default value, so it's arity is not fixed.
- Curried - functions with fixed arity can be curried, which means that calling the function with less parameters than the fixed arity, would return a new function that expects the remaining number of parameters, and so on. So if I call `R.prop` with 1 parameter (the property) it would return another function that expects 1 parameter (the object). That's not actually the classical definition of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20computer%20science,each%20takes%20a%20single%20argument.), but that's how Ramda works.
- Iteratee first/data last - the callback or the operator is passed first, and the data (object, array, etc...) is passed last. For example `R.prop` gets the property (the operator) first, and the data (the object) last. `_.get()` takes the object first, and than the path (the operator).

Since Lodash's functions have a non-fixed arity, expect all parameters at once, and are not iteratee first, you'll need to supply everything when calling the functions inside `_.flow()` (which works fine, and doesn't actually require the brackets):

```
const test = aRouteId &&
  _.flow(
    arr => lodashFind(arr, (r: any) => r['pointIndex'] === aTerraIndex && r['routeIndex'] === aRouteIndex),
    obj => lodashGet(obj, 'wayOfLiving')
  )(allSelectedRoutes)
```

It's easier to convert Ramda to [Lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) which functions has a fixed arity, are curried, and are iteratee first. I would still prefer Ramda, since lodash/fp lacks a lot of Ramda's functions (R.eveolve, R.applySpec, R.chain, for example), and the documentation is horrible. This would work with lodash/fp:

```
const test = aRouteId &&
  _.flow(
    lodashFpFind((r: any) => r['pointIndex'] === aTerraIndex && r['routeIndex'] === aRouteIndex),
    lodashFpGet('wayOfLiving')
)(allSelectedRoutes)
```